# Split large DataFrame into smaller with no repeating labels in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like:

```
Time, Col1, Col2, ... , label

.     .     .           label1 
.     .     .           label2 
.     .     .           label3
.     .     .           label1 
.     .     .           label2
.     .     .           label3
```

I want to split the DataFrame into n smaller data frames but I don't want the label to repeat at all. Is there a way to do this easily? Im currently using pandas. I tried playing with the indexes but didn't get very far and if I did it was painfully slow. I feel like there is an easy way to do this but can't find it

Comment: does the labels always consecutive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `groupby` it with `cumcount`

```
G = df.groupby(df.groupby('label').cumcount())

d = {x : y for x , y in G}
```

Comment: You have `in` twice, this should be `d = {x : y for x , y in G}`

Comment: Or as @BEN_YO once taught me long ago... `d = dict(tuple(df.groupby(df.groupby('label').cumcount())))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use duplicate function:

```
df_1 = df[~df.duplicated(subset=['label'])]
df = df[df.duplicated(subset=['label'])]
```

and iterate with that until there are no more duplicates